# Deploying OpenVINO models on AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, openvino, aws-lambda-edge, aws-lambda-layers

`AWS Lambda` limits the size of code and dependencies to `250mb` and so installing `OpenVINO` is not viable. However, `OpenVINO` offers a [Deployment Manager](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_install_guides_deployment_manager_tool.html) which creates a deployment package by assembling the model, IR files, your application, and associated dependencies into a runtime package for your target device.

The problem is the Deployment Package does not support `Python` whereas `AWS Lambda` does not support C++. Is there any workaround for this? Is it possible to deploy `OpenVINO` models on `AWS Lambda`?

Answer (score 1):

> AWS Lambda does not support C++

AWS **does support C++**, just not out of the box from the console:

- [Introducing the C++ Lambda Runtime](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-c-lambda-runtime/):

> AWS is releasing a reference implementation of a **C++ runtime for Lambda**. This C++ runtime brings the simplicity and expressiveness of interpreted languages while maintaining the superiority of C++ performance and low memory footprint.

Thus one way to overcome your problem would be to use the reference example of C++ lambda provided by AWS, and modify it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually a couple of ways to solve this issue: 1) Docker, 2) Elastic File Store.

1. At AWS reinvent in 2020, AWS announced it enabled you to create custom docker containers as part of AWS Lambda that can hold up to 10GB: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/
2. You can integrate an AWS Elastic File Store (EFS) and use this as a persistent location for compiled code, or other libraries/models to directly import from your lambda functions directly: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-efs-for-aws-lambda-in-your-serverless-applications/

In your docker container you can um install open-vino - I.E: `yum -y install openvino-2022.1.0`

And use it directly inside of AWS Lambda.